# Conditions for a dual geometry to be a model of incidence geometry

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I study Euclidean geometry
I know, models of incidence geometry must satisfy 3 axioms:

$A1$ Two distinct points belong to exactly one line.

$A2$ There are at least 2 points on every line.

$A3$ There are 3 different points, that do not belong to one line.

I have learned about dual models.
I know that dual models of incidence geometry must satisfy axioms

$A^*1$ Two different lines have exactly one common point.

$A^*2$ Every point belongs to at least 2 different lines.

$A^*3$ There are 3 distinct and not concurrent lines.

My questions are:

1. Do I understand the axioms right?
2. I have a model of incidence geometry $M$ and I make a dual geometry $M^*$. What condition must $M$ satisfy in order to $M^*$ be a model of incidence geometry?  And the proof of the claim too.

Comment: What is the source of these axioms for dual models? I can't see a relation between A1-A3 and A*1-A*3. Did you mean not concurrent lines in A*3?

Comment: Normally dual models arise by interchanging the roles of lines and points. For instance you should "translate" A2 to "Every point belongs to at least 2 lines" and A3 to "There are 3 distinct and not concurrent lines".

Comment: I tried to make the axioms $A^*1-A^*3$ by myself. Thanks for an explanation. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that incidence structure is a triple $M=(P,L,\epsilon)$, where $P$ is the set of points, $L$ is the set of lines, and $\epsilon$ is the incidence relation between points and lines i.e. $\epsilon\subseteq P\times L$.

Dual model $M^*$ to structure $M=(P,L,\epsilon)$ arises by interchanging the roles of point and lines i.e. $M^*=(L,P,\epsilon^{-1})$ which means that points become lines and vice versa.

As for question 2, it is self-evident that the dual model $M^*$ of some incidence structure $M$ is a model of incidence geometry (axioms A1-A3) if and only if axioms A*1-A*3 are satisfied in $M$.

Example: Any projective plane is a model for incidence geometry such that its dual model is as well a model for incidence geometry.